# Pandas remove/filter time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

If I have a lot of time series data, is it possible to remove any rows in the dataframe if its not on a 0, 15, 30, 45, minute time stamp?

For example I can make up some data on 5 minute intervals...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = pd.date_range('6/28/2013', periods=2000, freq='5min')
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=2000), index=time)

print(data)
```

But how would I filter to remove any row that doesnt fall on a 0, 15, 30, 45 minute time interval? Basically the end result would need to be 15 minutes only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `isin`

```
data[data.index.minute.isin([0,15,30,45])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since minutes are multiple of 15* like `[0,15,30,45]`, you can also use

```
data[(data.index.minute % 15) == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.Series.asfreq`

```
data.asfreq(‘15T’)

2013-06-28 00:00:00    21
2013-06-28 00:15:00    20
2013-06-28 00:30:00    92
2013-06-28 00:45:00    70
2013-06-28 01:00:00    86
2013-06-28 01:15:00    82
2013-06-28 01:30:00    13
...
```